# Store dark mode in localStorage across web-pages

Tags: javascript, local-storage, darkmode

Salutations! I'm developing a new blog and, as the title suggests, I'm trying to store my Dark Mode style-sheet in localStorage across web-pages. Currently if a user selects Dark Mode, but then refreshes the page or links to another web-page, the site reverts back to Light Mode again. I want it to remember the user's choice of mode (Light or Dark). This is my current JavaScript code:

```
function swapStylesheet(sheet) {
document.getElementById('swap').setAttribute('href', sheet); 
}
```

How might I apply localStorage to this code so that the browser remembers which style-sheet the user chose?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy using localStorage API.

In order to save to local storage:

```
function swapStylesheet(sheet) {
document.getElementById('swap').setAttribute('href', sheet); 
localStorage.setItem('swap', sheet);
}
```

To retrive from local storage:

```
function getLocalStorageSwapStyle(){
let style=localStorage.getItem('swap');
swapStyleSheet(style);
}
```

You may call `getLocalStorageSwapStyle` whenever you want. E.g: on page load or some certain event.

More info regarding localStorage API can be found here: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Thank you so much Skywarth! I tried calling those two JS functions at the start of the HTML page of my blog and it didn't seem to work... I put them in a file called mode.js and called it at the start of the HTML page with the <script> tag. Am I doing it incorrectly? My blog is https://xy4.co/blog if that helps you help me troubleshoot. =P

Comment: You have to call swapStyleSheet function whenever user switches dark mode. This way it'll save current dark mode selection to local storage. getLocalStorageSwapStyle() function should be the one to be called on page load.

Comment: Ugh, still can't seem to get it to work. I put this on the HTML page: <body onload="getLocalStorageSwapStyle()"> ... and call the dark mode function with this link: <a class="mode" onClick="swapStylesheet('../style/blog-dark.css')">Dark Mode</a> ... and put the JS code you gave me in a file called mode.js and called it in the <head> tag with: <script type="application/javascript" src="../style/mode.js"></script> ... Not sure what I'm doing wrong =|

Comment: Checked your website, error indicates a typo in the function name. change function name 'swapStylesheet' to 'swapStyleSheet'. Remember, JS is case-sensitive.